# How do I get the base URL in web app (i.e., /exec vs. /dev)?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

How do I get the base URL from within the `doGet(e)` function?

If I am writing an HTML template that is setting anchors, how do I determine the base URL? It could be .../exec or .../dev.

I do not see the URL in the parameters.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#properties

Answer (score 3):

[techhowch's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614585/how-do-i-get-the-base-url-in-web-app-i-e-exec-vs-dev/55615303#comment97923208_55614585) got me going in the right direction.

`ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` does the trick!

Documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl()
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#properties